# Can I fix cross-browser CSS issues with <use xlink>-based SVG sprite without resorting to full inline code?

Tags: css, svg, cross-browser

***SUMMARY:** Some SVG-targeting CSS effects don't work in Chrome & IE (Firefox is fine) on a `<use xlink>` SVG sprite but the same CSS works absolutely fine when the same SVG code is truly inline.*

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/x8vg8k4p/5/

---

I am currently using `<svg><use xlink:href="#symbol-id" /></svg>` blocks to call SVG code from an SVG sprite (as an external file) imported via PHP dynamically.

Some CSS effects are applied to the SVG, both as standard and on hover. All these effects work absolutely fine on Firefox, but on both IE and Chrome, they don't:

- The `fill` attribute on the `circle` does not take effect
- The `opacity` settings on two internal parts of the SVG (the cross by default and the thumb on hover) do not take effect

[image: screenshot to show browser differences]

I believe there is nothing wrong with the CSS as the same code works absolutely fine if the SVG code is **inline** and not imported via sprite id reference, which the fiddle demonstrates very clearly.

I've struggled for hours, moving bits of code around, adding and removing extra attributes, and not been able to solve this.

*What follows are the relevant excerpts of the full code which can be seen on the JSfiddle link - it seems detrimental to readability to include all code here in the question, but I'm happy to edit the question if someone tells me this is bad form.*

**not working:**

```
<a><svg><use xlink:href="#thumbs-up" /></svg></a>
```

**working:**

```
<a><svg><!-- truly inline SVG code here --></svg></a>
```

**these parts of the CSS are the bits that fail on Chrome and IE:**

```
a svg circle            {fill: #4291c2;}
a svg path#cross        {opacity: 0;}
a:hover svg circle      {fill: #91c142;}
a:hover svg path#cross  {opacity: 1;}
a:hover svg g#hand      {opacity: 0;}
```

**finally the SVG code itself:**

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="thumbs-up" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50"/>
        <g id="hand">
            <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="64.287,37.926 64.287,71.491 80.925,71.491 73.044,37.926     "/>
            <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M54.425,41.857c0-2.634-2.811-4.295-5.025-5.155c-2.728-1.059-4.069-4.203-1.565-8.379
                c2.146-3.58-2.084-8.795-6.628-6.058c-5.205,3.134-4.073,11.161-2.468,15.889c0.61,1.798-0.435,1.743-1.756,1.743
                c-1.081,0-5.646,0-5.646,0h-8.469c-0.998,0-3.288,6.399-2.289,6.399h10.729c-0.188,0.5-0.406,1.391-0.619,2.544H19.768
                c-1.152,0-1.919,7.2-0.714,7.2h10.859c-0.035,0.842-0.049,1.695-0.038,2.544H19.372c-1.195,0-0.277,6.256,0.803,6.256h10.413
                c0.245,0.95,0.561,1.813,0.962,2.544H21.331c-1.294,0,1.405,5.811,3.027,5.811h6.978c4.925,0,13.934,0,17.805,0
                c3.872,0,5.378-5.477,11.86-5.477V43.891C61.001,43.891,54.425,44.12,54.425,41.857z"/>
        </g>
        <path id="cross" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50.042,54.392L39.967,66.389c-0.659,0.854-1.478,1.281-2.454,1.281
            c-0.879,0-1.612-0.306-2.198-0.915c-0.586-0.61-0.879-1.355-0.879-2.234c0-0.781,0.195-1.404,0.586-1.867l11.065-13.199
            L35.864,37.311c-0.464-0.536-0.696-1.147-0.696-1.831c0-0.806,0.286-1.531,0.859-2.179c0.572-0.646,1.31-0.971,2.211-0.971
            c1.023,0,1.852,0.382,2.485,1.145l9.285,11.188l9.547-11.273c0.586-0.706,1.318-1.06,2.198-1.06c0.781,0,1.49,0.275,2.125,0.824
            c0.635,0.55,0.953,1.251,0.953,2.105c0,0.83-0.135,1.404-0.403,1.722L54.021,49.495l10.921,13.158
            c0.415,0.463,0.623,1.041,0.623,1.729c0,0.937-0.312,1.718-0.935,2.345c-0.622,0.629-1.337,0.942-2.142,0.942
            c-0.952,0-1.782-0.427-2.49-1.282L50.042,54.392z"/>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Firefox is buggy and does not implement the SVG specification in this regard. When we fix it it will work like IE/Chrome.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673441/svg-use-element-and-hover-style

Comment: @birdspider - thanks for spotting the dupe. How painful to put so much effort into writing a post (and searching beforehand) only to find it wasted, arrghh!

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for info. Seems crazy that Firefox working so well is actually buggy. So the bottom line is that <use> is of no value if you want to apply CSS effects to elements, and I need to just use simple inline SVG?

Comment: @MattMorrison if it helps - your question (among new ones) was the best formatted/explained I have encountered in my short SO carreer, I felt sorry the moment I posted the dupe :/

Comment: @birdspider - thanks, good to know! I'm new here but a long time fan/user so I'm trying to make sure I do everything properly :)

Comment: Did you give a try to insert it as <object> and link the css from the svg?

Comment: This bug has been fixed in Firefox. Firefox now displays the fiddle in the question the same as Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best you can do is to use css custom properties:

```css
:root {
  --circle-fill: #4291c2;
  --hand-fill: #ffffff;
  --cross-fill: #ffffff;
  --cross-opacity: 0;
  --hand-opacity: 1;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  display: inline-block; 
  border: none; 
  cursor: pointer; 
  position: relative; 
  width: 25px; 
  height: 25px; 
  margin: 0 2px 0 5px;
}

a, a * {
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
}

a svg {
  position: absolute; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%;
}

a:hover {
  opacity: 1.0; 
  transform: rotate(-5deg) scale(1.5);
}

a:hover .thumb {
  --circle-fill: #91c142;
  --hand-opacity: 0;
  --cross-opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <symbol id="thumbs-up" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="49.999" r="50" style="fill: var(--circle-fill)"/>
  <g id="hand">
   <polygon style="fill: var(--hand-fill); fill-opacity: var(--hand-opacity)" points="64.287,37.926 64.287,71.491 80.925,71.491 73.044,37.926"/>
   <path style="fill: var(--hand-fill); fill-opacity: var(--hand-opacity)" d="M54.425,41.857c0-2.634-2.811-4.295-5.025-5.155c-2.728-1.059-4.069-4.203-1.565-8.379
    c2.146-3.58-2.084-8.795-6.628-6.058c-5.205,3.134-4.073,11.161-2.468,15.889c0.61,1.798-0.435,1.743-1.756,1.743
    c-1.081,0-5.646,0-5.646,0h-8.469c-0.998,0-3.288,6.399-2.289,6.399h10.729c-0.188,0.5-0.406,1.391-0.619,2.544H19.768
    c-1.152,0-1.919,7.2-0.714,7.2h10.859c-0.035,0.842-0.049,1.695-0.038,2.544H19.372c-1.195,0-0.277,6.256,0.803,6.256h10.413
    c0.245,0.95,0.561,1.813,0.962,2.544H21.331c-1.294,0,1.405,5.811,3.027,5.811h6.978c4.925,0,13.934,0,17.805,0
    c3.872,0,5.378-5.477,11.86-5.477V43.891C61.001,43.891,54.425,44.12,54.425,41.857z"/>
  </g>
    <path id="cross" style="fill: var(--cross-fill); fill-opacity: var(--cross-opacity)" d="M50.042,54.392L39.967,66.389c-0.659,0.854-1.478,1.281-2.454,1.281
   c-0.879,0-1.612-0.306-2.198-0.915c-0.586-0.61-0.879-1.355-0.879-2.234c0-0.781,0.195-1.404,0.586-1.867l11.065-13.199
   L35.864,37.311c-0.464-0.536-0.696-1.147-0.696-1.831c0-0.806,0.286-1.531,0.859-2.179c0.572-0.646,1.31-0.971,2.211-0.971
   c1.023,0,1.852,0.382,2.485,1.145l9.285,11.188l9.547-11.273c0.586-0.706,1.318-1.06,2.198-1.06c0.781,0,1.49,0.275,2.125,0.824
   c0.635,0.55,0.953,1.251,0.953,2.105c0,0.83-0.135,1.404-0.403,1.722L54.021,49.495l10.921,13.158
   c0.415,0.463,0.623,1.041,0.623,1.729c0,0.937-0.312,1.718-0.935,2.345c-0.622,0.629-1.337,0.942-2.142,0.942
   c-0.952,0-1.782-0.427-2.49-1.282L50.042,54.392z"/>
 </symbol>
</svg>

<a><svg><use class="thumb" xlink:href="#thumbs-up"/></svg></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not address an element that is referenced via use. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13674240/435545) is a detailed answer to your question.

Also, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27065518/435545), which talks about a possible workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you have to remove "fill" attribute from your svg icons.
Also my advice is using this one https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse for cross-browser solution