# SVG - Accessing individual nodes on xlink:href external source

Tags: css, svg, symbols, xlink

I was looking at Chris Coier's SVG tricks on CSS-tricks.com and also recently saw him at a conference where he talked about the powers of SVGs and how you can keep all assets in one external svg file.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

  <symbol id="beaker" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="shape-icon-2" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

Then, you could just use it like this:

```
<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-icon-1" />
</svg>

<svg class="icon">
  <use xlink:href="#shape-icon-2" />
</svg>
```

Sounds great! BUT, I want to be able to access individual nodes in each symbol and altering them with CSS like I normally would if the SVG was inline in the HTMl.

Take a look at this CodePen:
http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/Hwcxp

I thought I could do this, but I can't get it to work:

```
.icon path{
  fill: green;
}
```

This does, but this alters the actual source svg

```
#beaker path {
 fill: green;
}
```

What I want to do is reuse a graphical element in a grid. And on hover, alter a node in the svg. But only on the node in that particular parent. Not all of them.

Comment: You cannot access part of a re-used graphic with CSS selectors; selectors can only apply to the original graphic (affecting all copies of the icon) or to the use element itself (affecting the styles *inherited* by the icon instance).  

In order to have a hover effect that works cross-browser, you need to redefine the part of the icon that you want to change so that it uses inherited styles.  Then, you can define a hover effect on the use element or its parent SVG.  [More details on this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13673441/3128209); marking this as duplicate.

Comment: Note that while the linked question specifically relates to hover effects, it also works for any other style changes you want to make on a single instance of the icon.

Comment: I see, so it's still back to adding the SVG to the document inline then. Atleast for these kinds of things. Thanks you for the elaborated answer! :)

Answer (score -2):

Firefox does some unknown thing where you can style it this way.

edit:
To be more precise:
Firefox seems to turn that symbol kinda into  in the DOM.
http://codepen.io/Type-Style/pen/EaGbam

```
.hoverME:hover path, .hoverME:hover circle  {
  fill: red;  
}
```

This also works with an external file. (Unfortunatly it does not with crossDomain Files)

> "But you can insert just the class name of the path. That will work."
>   I mean as long as you stay within the SVG with your selectors it will work.

```
 circle:hover, path:hover {
  fill: red;  
}
```

Comment: This answer is unclear and doesn't seem to apply to the question above. Add some code to support it, and explain why. (Also, why Firefox? the question doesn't specify any browser in particular, will this work on other browsers?)

Comment: Firefox has a known bug, when we fix it, it won't work this way any more so there's not much point suggesting that anyone use it.

Comment: Thanks @RobertLongson. I'll agree.