# Different behaviour updating SVG elements created with <use> tags in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I've made a cut down version of the issue I'm having in the JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nm1h7g02/6/).

I use d3.js to dynamically add SVG path elements with class `symbol` to the group with id `grouped-shapes` in the following `defs` tag:

```
<defs>
  <g id="grouped-shapes">
    ...
  </g>
</defs>
```

I then use this definition twice, once directly and once via a reference to the first `use` tag:

```
<g id="first-triangle"> 
  <use xlink:href="#grouped-shapes" transform="translate(100, 100)"/>
</g>

<g id="second-triangle">
  <use xlink:href="#first-triangle" transform="translate(200, 200) 
  rotate(30)"/>          
</g>
```

(In this example case I could easily avoid the problem by working out everything as a transformation of the original grouped-shapes instead of doing this indirect transformation, but in my real use case this would be more complicated.)

I then set up an event listener to remove paths with class `symbol` on clicking the container div:

```
document.getElementById("kaleidoscope-container")
  .addEventListener("click", function( event ) {
    d3.selectAll(".symbol").remove();
   }, false);
```

In Chrome, both groups update on clicking, but in Firefox only the first one does.

Which of these behaviours is correct? I'm looking to be able to update in both instances, as in Chrome - what is the correct way of going about this?

Comment: I referenced a runnable JSFiddle example at the beginning of the post. Please let me know if this is inaccessible for some reason, I haven't used it before. https://jsfiddle.net/nm1h7g02/6/

Comment: Chrome is correct, this appears to be a bug in Firefox updating the use elements properly, you should [report it](http://bugzilla.mozilla.org)

Comment: @RobertLongson For reasons explained in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594422/4235784) to [*Change Part of Symbol ColorSVG*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29589611/4235784) I think all mentioned browsers err on this. No child element of `<use>` should be selectable/accessible using CSS selectors.

Comment: @altocumulus It seems like in this case the OP is adding elements to the symbol and only one <use> instance is displaying them, no?

Comment: @RobertLongson That‘s not my point, though. Both cases try you access the innards of a non-exposed DOM tree, which should not be possible as per the spec. The nesting in this question just adds to the complexity.