# SVG: How to change "fill" color of a symbol in an external svg sprite

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG sprite in an external file `symbols.svg` and I use code like this to insert images from the sprite into an HTML file:

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="symbols.svg#icon-twitter" />
</svg>
```

I want to change FILL color of the svg-image on hover, how can I do that with CSS?

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562989/how-to-style-one-particular-svg-path-in-css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<svg class="svg_hover">
    <use xlink:href="symbols.svg#icon-twitter" />
</svg>
```

css:

```
.svg_hover:hover{ fill: #f00; }
```