# SVG how to change fill colour of a specific path in a specific SVG image provided via a file in vanilla HTML5

Tags: css, svg

I have a local (non web server) external SVG file with two paths in a group. I would like to have multiple external SVG files and I would like to be able to change the colour of a path of a specific SVG via it's svg id and path id. I could not find an example of this on Stack Overflow, the one that came the closest was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29562989/how-to-style-one-particular-svg-path-in-css), but it's answers did not help me.

My SVG code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg4554"
   width="323"
   height="352.66666"
   viewBox="0 0 323 352.66666"
   sodipodi:docname="ValueChain1Plan.svg"
   inkscape:version="0.92.4 (5da689c313, 2019-01-14)">
  <metadata
     id="metadata4560">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <defs
     id="defs4558" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="1280"
     inkscape:window-height="636"
     id="namedview4556"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="true"
     inkscape:zoom="1.3298677"
     inkscape:cx="161.5"
     inkscape:cy="176.33333"
     inkscape:window-x="-8"
     inkscape:window-y="-8"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1"
     inkscape:current-layer="g4564" />
  <g
     id="g4564">
    <path
       id="path4570"
       style="display:inline;fill:#3376fe;stroke-width:0.33333334"       
       d="m 162.16602,3.3222656 c -6.71373,0 -13.42616,0.1712712 -15.33204,0.515625 -1.46666,0.264997 -3.65686,0.4846713 -4.86523,0.4882813 -1.20836,0.00361 -2.93206,0.2308906 -3.83203,0.5039062 -0.89997,0.2730154 -2.38607,0.5036389 -3.30274,0.5136719 -0.91666,0.010031 -2.26666,0.2358077 -3,0.5 -0.73333,0.2641927 -1.90036,0.481605 -2.59375,0.484375 -0.69338,0.00276 -1.80081,0.2308594 -2.45898,0.5058594 -0.65817,0.275 -1.63252,0.5 -2.16602,0.5 -0.5335,0 -1.50785,0.225 -2.16601,0.5 -0.65817,0.275 -1.51614,0.4989471 -1.90625,0.4980468 -0.39012,-9.066e-4 -1.38399,0.209973 -2.20899,0.46875 -0.825,0.2587774 -2.32565,0.7052555 -3.33398,0.9921876 -3.59969,1.0243302 -9.5052,2.9849522 -9.81641,3.2597652 -0.17416,0.1538 -0.6329,0.28125 -1.01953,0.28125 -0.38663,0 -0.99374,0.219112 -1.34961,0.488282 -0.35587,0.269169 -0.92529,0.4942 -1.26367,0.5 -0.33838,0.0058 -1.01338,0.222158 -1.5,0.480468 -0.486616,0.25831 -1.708462,0.801091 -2.716796,1.205078 -3.965043,1.588592 -14.881875,6.897492 -17.167968,8.34961 -0.55,0.349358 -1.225,0.733221 -1.5,0.853516 -0.46694,0.204253 -4.916324,2.902113 -6.933594,4.203124 -0.494443,0.318889 -1.235938,0.754043 -1.648438,0.96875 -0.4125,0.214709 -0.75,0.516017 -0.75,0.669922 0,0.153906 -0.156456,0.28125 -0.347656,0.28125 -0.1912,0 -1.12935,0.58807 -2.083984,1.306641 -0.954633,0.71857 -2.443414,1.805419 -3.308594,2.416016 -1.824493,1.287626 -7.014432,5.304896 -7.259766,5.61914 -0.09167,0.117416 -1.216666,1.087164 -2.5,2.15625 -3.345416,2.786917 -12.87763,12.3958 -16.371093,16.501953 -4.09912,4.818037 -7.93063,9.920599 -11.128907,14.822266 -0.940627,1.441603 -4.900605,8.008989 -5.130859,8.509766 -0.126443,0.275 -0.736793,1.4 -1.357422,2.5 -0.62063,1.1 -1.455655,2.675 -1.855469,3.5 -1.216297,2.509777 -2.736244,5.772756 -3.21875,6.912109 -1.05226,2.484733 -1.563977,3.637267 -1.988281,4.472655 -0.24716,0.48662 -0.455137,1.16162 -0.460937,1.5 -0.0058,0.33838 -0.23083,0.90779 -0.5,1.26367 -0.269169,0.35587 -0.488282,0.90027 -0.488282,1.21094 0,0.31067 -0.224176,0.9944 -0.498046,1.51953 -0.273871,0.52512 -0.498901,1.28387 -0.5,1.68555 -0.0011,0.40168 -0.141319,0.81533 -0.310547,0.91992 -0.1692303,0.10459 -0.4085077,0.67579 -0.5312504,1.26953 -0.2098087,1.01488 -0.5952163,2.35712 -1.6992187,5.91406 -0.2560636,0.825 -0.4637905,1.81888 -0.4628907,2.20899 9.067e-4,0.39011 -0.2230468,1.24808 -0.4980468,1.90625 -0.275,0.65817 -0.5030894,1.613 -0.5058594,2.12305 -0.00276,0.51006 -0.2201823,1.52838 -0.484375,2.26171 -0.2641923,0.73333 -0.48997,1.93268 -0.5,2.66602 -0.010032,0.73333 -0.2406565,2.06878 -0.5136719,2.96875 -0.2730156,0.89997 -0.4960937,2.47686 -0.4960937,3.50195 0,1.0251 -0.2223242,2.91205 -0.4941406,4.19532 -0.3847492,1.81642 -0.4931282,4.95559 -0.4863282,14.16796 0.0048,6.50833 0.155286,12.50704 0.3339844,13.33204 0.1786983,0.825 0.4620917,3.03013 0.6308594,4.90039 0.1687677,1.87026 0.4675599,3.69898 0.6621094,4.0625 0.1945496,0.36352 0.3535156,1.32661 0.3535156,2.14062 0,0.814 0.225,2.11706 0.5,2.89649 0.275,0.77944 0.4989536,1.81185 0.4980468,2.29296 -9.066e-4,0.48112 0.2109048,1.55 0.4707032,2.375 0.5435626,1.7261 1.0943192,3.85484 1.5507812,5.98633 0.175058,0.81745 0.4686717,1.63469 0.6503906,1.81641 0.1817192,0.18171 0.3300782,0.68542 0.3300782,1.11914 0,0.43372 0.172761,1.11167 0.3847656,1.50781 0.2120047,0.39613 0.502416,1.17421 0.644531,1.72852 0.272946,1.06462 1.127502,3.55344 1.605469,4.67383 0.156423,0.36667 0.541631,1.34296 0.855469,2.16796 0.525218,1.38066 0.761598,1.94838 2.007812,4.83204 0.92599,2.14269 5.213136,10.75437 6.140625,12.33398 0.538234,0.91666 1.381323,2.41731 1.873047,3.33398 0.491724,0.91667 1.253214,2.14297 1.691406,2.72657 0.438193,0.5836 0.796875,1.13621 0.796875,1.22851 0,0.0923 0.701884,1.19037 1.560547,2.43946 0.858663,1.24909 2.017044,2.94648 2.574219,3.77148 2.182113,3.23102 6.849339,9.04251 10.679688,13.29883 2.803007,3.11474 9.600526,9.85711 12.310546,12.21094 1.260317,1.09467 2.534015,2.22548 2.832032,2.51367 0.298016,0.28818 1.492629,1.26449 2.654296,2.16797 1.161671,0.90349 3.036019,2.36651 4.166016,3.25195 1.957207,1.53363 11.239178,7.85118 12.244141,8.33398 0.26233,0.12602 0.928515,0.52676 1.478515,0.88868 0.55,0.36193 1.299349,0.81122 1.666016,1 0.366667,0.18878 1.116016,0.63276 1.666016,0.98632 1.1498,0.73914 12.565175,6.47053 15.917968,7.99219 1.23799,0.56186 2.466779,1.02149 2.730469,1.02149 0.26369,0 0.568622,0.14572 0.677735,0.32226 0.10911,0.17655 0.680325,0.46309 1.269531,0.63867 0.589211,0.17559 1.895961,0.64436 2.904301,1.04102 1.00833,0.39667 2.13333,0.79802 2.5,0.89062 0.36666,0.0926 1.11796,0.36152 1.66796,0.59766 1.47386,0.6328 3.21969,1.22277 4.16602,1.4082 0.45833,0.0898 1.3051,0.37453 1.88281,0.63282 0.57771,0.25828 1.30869,0.46875 1.62305,0.46875 0.31435,0 1.34192,0.24253 2.2832,0.5371 3.44682,1.07883 4.06918,1.25329 5.37696,1.50977 3.44485,0.67561 5.1274,1.05194 6.62304,1.48438 0.89188,0.25787 2.16558,0.47065 2.83203,0.47265 0.66645,0.002 1.94769,0.22698 2.84766,0.5 0.89997,0.27301 2.50357,0.4961 3.5625,0.4961 1.05892,0 2.34718,0.16389 2.86328,0.36328 0.5161,0.19939 3.18945,0.50555 5.93945,0.68164 2.75,0.17608 6.2737,0.43976 7.83204,0.58594 4.21344,0.39515 11.43038,0.40436 14.83398,0.0176 1.65,-0.18755 5.25,-0.46958 8,-0.625 2.75,-0.15542 5.42139,-0.44857 5.9375,-0.65234 0.5161,-0.20377 1.7925,-0.37109 2.83594,-0.37109 1.04344,0 2.42205,-0.16793 3.0625,-0.375 0.64046,-0.20708 2.06406,-0.48471 3.16406,-0.61524 1.88591,-0.22379 2.90316,-0.43472 6.5,-1.3457 0.825,-0.20894 2.175,-0.49091 3,-0.62696 0.825,-0.13603 2.02435,-0.41101 2.66602,-0.61132 0.64166,-0.20031 2.06796,-0.61249 3.16796,-0.91602 1.1,-0.30354 2.45,-0.70471 3,-0.89258 0.55,-0.18787 1.5987,-0.48834 2.33204,-0.66601 0.73333,-0.17767 1.47622,-0.4639 1.65039,-0.63672 0.17416,-0.17282 0.62416,-0.31541 1,-0.31641 0.37583,-10e-4 1.11355,-0.22613 1.63867,-0.5 0.52512,-0.27387 1.15647,-0.49804 1.4043,-0.49804 0.45652,0 2.19611,-0.67878 3.91796,-1.53125 0.51903,-0.25697 1.09661,-0.46875 1.28321,-0.46875 0.1866,0 0.88727,-0.23485 1.55664,-0.52344 2.31473,-0.99794 3.2225,-1.39056 4.67578,-2.01563 2.94186,-1.26533 14.51079,-7.17821 16.42773,-8.39648 0.48797,-0.31012 1.61297,-0.99654 2.5,-1.52539 2.88192,-1.71822 11.46697,-7.56551 12.94532,-8.81641 0.36666,-0.31025 1.64231,-1.30184 2.83398,-2.20508 9.24844,-7.01007 22.53581,-20.78607 28.81055,-29.86914 0.74545,-1.07908 2.14297,-3.09683 3.10547,-4.48242 0.9625,-1.38559 1.75,-2.65185 1.75,-2.81445 0,-0.16259 0.12139,-0.34515 0.26953,-0.40625 0.24596,-0.10146 3.32169,-5.1015 3.86133,-6.27735 0.12619,-0.275 0.73549,-1.4 1.35351,-2.5 2.68371,-4.77671 5.88477,-11.76877 8.05078,-17.58398 1.86369,-5.00357 2.30792,-6.34961 3.16602,-9.58398 0.21888,-0.825 0.60175,-1.97113 0.84961,-2.54883 0.24787,-0.57771 0.44922,-1.45095 0.44922,-1.93946 0,-0.48852 0.16681,-1.19811 0.36914,-1.57617 0.20232,-0.37805 0.49561,-1.45547 0.65234,-2.39453 0.38695,-2.31837 0.92047,-4.96256 1.49805,-7.42773 0.26477,-1.13009 0.48047,-2.73313 0.48047,-3.5625 0,-0.82937 0.24853,-2.53043 0.55078,-3.7793 0.46648,-1.9273 0.54615,-4.36214 0.53515,-16.10352 -0.009,-9.24769 -0.14057,-14.38582 -0.39843,-15.5 -0.21215,-0.91667 -0.51324,-2.94167 -0.66993,-4.5 -0.15669,-1.55833 -0.44911,-3.25538 -0.65039,-3.77148 -0.20128,-0.5161 -0.36718,-1.53443 -0.36718,-2.26172 0,-0.72728 -0.225,-1.86137 -0.5,-2.51953 -0.275,-0.65817 -0.5,-1.63252 -0.5,-2.16602 0,-0.5335 -0.225,-1.50784 -0.5,-2.16601 -0.275,-0.65817 -0.49905,-1.51614 -0.49805,-1.90625 10e-4,-0.63643 -0.38789,-2.05195 -1.39063,-5.04297 -0.18439,-0.55 -0.48248,-1.60064 -0.66015,-2.33398 -0.17767,-0.73333 -0.4639,-1.47427 -0.63672,-1.64844 -0.17282,-0.17416 -0.31541,-0.62416 -0.31641,-1 -0.001,-0.37583 -0.22613,-1.11355 -0.5,-1.63867 -0.27387,-0.52512 -0.49804,-1.20886 -0.49804,-1.51953 0,-0.31069 -0.21912,-0.85703 -0.48829,-1.2129 -0.26917,-0.35587 -0.494,-0.8484 -0.5,-1.0957 -0.006,-0.24729 -0.24657,-0.9986 -0.53515,-1.667968 -0.28859,-0.66937 -0.73574,-1.706177 -0.99219,-2.304687 -3.41208,-7.96332 -7.48743,-15.559498 -12.48437,-23.271484 C 291.06882,63.624838 279.7856,50.836728 270,42.453125 264.73939,37.946212 253.12997,29.408369 250.65625,28.226562 c -0.26977,-0.128879 -0.94023,-0.530652 -1.49023,-0.892578 -0.55,-0.361926 -1.29935,-0.811223 -1.66602,-1 -0.36667,-0.188777 -1.11602,-0.633099 -1.66602,-0.986328 -3.18216,-2.043689 -12.72716,-6.752789 -19.5,-9.621094 -0.64166,-0.271746 -1.56611,-0.696199 -2.05273,-0.943359 -0.48662,-0.24716 -1.18911,-0.449219 -1.5625,-0.449219 -0.37339,0 -0.76455,-0.139365 -0.86914,-0.308593 -0.10459,-0.169228 -0.64874,-0.4082 -1.20899,-0.53125 -0.56022,-0.123051 -1.42029,-0.432862 -1.9121,-0.689453 -0.49182,-0.256592 -1.13958,-0.467652 -1.43946,-0.46875 -0.29987,-0.0011 -0.97487,-0.226131 -1.5,-0.5 -0.52512,-0.273874 -1.20012,-0.498904 -1.5,-0.5 -0.29987,-0.0011 -0.97487,-0.226131 -1.5,-0.5 -0.52512,-0.273871 -1.33914,-0.498901 -1.80664,-0.5 -0.4675,-0.0011 -0.99798,-0.150313 -1.17969,-0.332032 -0.18172,-0.181718 -0.99895,-0.4753324 -1.8164,-0.6503904 C 205.85484,8.8970536 203.7261,8.3462971 202,7.8027344 c -0.825,-0.2597983 -1.89322,-0.4716028 -2.375,-0.4707032 -0.48178,9.07e-4 -1.41605,-0.2230468 -2.07422,-0.4980468 -0.65816,-0.275 -1.76364,-0.5030894 -2.45703,-0.5058594 -0.69339,-0.00276 -1.86042,-0.2201823 -2.59375,-0.484375 -0.73333,-0.2641923 -2.0385,-0.4880437 -2.90039,-0.4960938 -0.86189,-0.00805 -2.43054,-0.2386718 -3.48633,-0.5136718 -1.0558,-0.275 -2.82628,-0.5042025 -3.93359,-0.5078125 -1.10732,-0.00361 -3.21302,-0.2232843 -4.67969,-0.4882813 -1.90588,-0.3443538 -8.62026,-0.515625 -15.33398,-0.515625 z m 0,6.8574224 c 5.94493,-0.0027 16.04889,0.554446 18.40234,1.015624 1.32144,0.258949 3.19774,0.47261 4.16797,0.47461 0.97023,0.002 2.50042,0.226985 3.40039,0.5 0.89997,0.273016 2.20227,0.496094 2.89453,0.496094 0.69226,0 1.68117,0.16629 2.19727,0.36914 0.5161,0.20285 1.76315,0.492388 2.77148,0.642578 1.96876,0.293244 3.93882,0.765278 6.33398,1.519532 0.825,0.259798 1.90314,0.471603 2.39649,0.470703 0.49334,-9.07e-4 0.98053,0.135352 1.08398,0.302734 0.10344,0.167381 0.82532,0.409766 1.60352,0.539063 0.77821,0.129298 1.82133,0.443944 2.31641,0.697265 0.49503,0.253322 1.1901,0.458985 1.54492,0.458985 0.35481,0 1.07449,0.224176 1.59961,0.498046 0.52513,0.273871 1.25442,0.504719 1.62109,0.511719 0.36667,0.007 0.95858,0.232784 1.31445,0.501953 0.35587,0.26917 0.98402,0.488282 1.39649,0.488282 0.41248,0 0.83284,0.133851 0.93359,0.296875 0.10076,0.163024 0.59566,0.393411 1.10156,0.511718 0.5059,0.118306 1.36993,0.422047 1.91993,0.673829 0.55,0.251778 1.675,0.717774 2.5,1.037109 3.36598,1.302876 12.922,5.909232 16.5,7.953125 1.1,0.628364 2.60065,1.470434 3.33398,1.871094 0.73333,0.400661 1.97922,1.162905 2.76758,1.693359 0.78836,0.530453 1.48968,0.962891 1.56054,0.962891 0.0709,0 1.07696,0.652241 2.23438,1.449218 1.15743,0.79698 3.15417,2.170288 4.4375,3.050782 8.50828,5.837496 19.62178,15.969235 26.51172,24.167968 1.00142,1.191667 1.91135,2.240362 2.02148,2.332032 0.31576,0.262844 8.30078,10.943979 8.30078,11.103515 0,0.07866 0.84026,1.398794 1.86719,2.935547 1.02693,1.53675 2.0045,3.094271 2.17383,3.460938 0.16933,0.366667 0.82871,1.567968 1.46484,2.667968 0.63613,1.1 2.1496,4.025 3.36328,6.5 2.2387,4.565276 2.53349,5.196297 3.80079,8.166016 0.39118,0.91666 0.83162,1.89672 0.97851,2.17773 0.14688,0.28102 0.37092,0.99236 0.5,1.58008 0.12908,0.58771 0.37374,1.15322 0.54297,1.25781 0.16922,0.10461 0.30859,0.52699 0.30859,0.93946 0,0.41247 0.21912,1.04257 0.48829,1.39844 0.26917,0.35588 0.49495,0.94584 0.50195,1.3125 0.007,0.36667 0.23785,1.09792 0.51172,1.62304 0.27387,0.52512 0.499,1.27447 0.5,1.66602 0.001,0.39154 0.20242,1.09528 0.44726,1.56445 0.24484,0.46918 0.54578,1.4893 0.66992,2.26563 0.12415,0.77634 0.35712,1.66569 0.51758,1.97851 0.32736,0.63822 0.91965,3.31238 1.34375,6.07031 0.15506,1.00833 0.44754,2.25539 0.65039,2.77149 0.20285,0.5161 0.37105,1.5648 0.37305,2.33203 0.002,0.76723 0.22545,2.22019 0.49609,3.22852 0.27065,1.00834 0.49786,2.80834 0.50586,4 0.008,1.19167 0.23076,3.74296 0.49414,5.66796 0.61952,4.52856 0.62123,13.5694 0.004,17.83204 -0.26562,1.83334 -0.48814,4.33979 -0.49414,5.56836 -0.006,1.22855 -0.23477,3.09654 -0.50977,4.15234 -0.275,1.0558 -0.5,2.57256 -0.5,3.37109 0,0.79853 -0.15703,1.74344 -0.34765,2.09961 -0.19061,0.35617 -0.47976,1.58424 -0.64258,2.72852 -0.16282,1.14427 -0.47234,2.75508 -0.6875,3.58008 -1.38241,5.30046 -2.32321,8.62057 -2.74219,9.66796 -0.18334,0.45833 -0.45025,1.28204 -0.59375,1.83204 -0.30648,1.17471 -0.91688,2.91207 -1.54101,4.38476 -0.24484,0.57771 -0.44532,1.20206 -0.44532,1.38867 0,0.1866 -0.21668,0.76419 -0.48046,1.28321 -0.26379,0.51903 -0.7237,1.544 -1.02344,2.27734 -0.81347,1.99019 -1.24622,2.91125 -3.68164,7.83398 -2.62381,5.30355 -2.40001,4.89118 -5.14844,9.44532 -1.19167,1.97459 -2.31971,3.84329 -2.50586,4.15429 -1.90771,3.18717 -7.40589,10.53794 -11.27148,15.06641 -4.07335,4.77185 -12.5733,13.17589 -17.22266,17.0293 -3.42953,2.84242 -9.63221,7.59005 -11.06641,8.4707 -0.29857,0.18334 -1.64309,1.08334 -2.98828,2 -1.3452,0.91667 -2.59596,1.74228 -2.77929,1.83398 -0.18334,0.0917 -0.93269,0.55171 -1.66602,1.02344 -0.73333,0.47173 -1.55898,0.95909 -1.83398,1.08203 -0.275,0.12294 -0.725,0.37174 -1,0.55274 -3.1374,2.06508 -12.16923,6.56893 -17.75782,8.85547 -1.14145,0.46702 -2.37552,0.97377 -2.74218,1.12695 -0.36667,0.15318 -1.34102,0.53611 -2.16602,0.85156 -0.825,0.31545 -1.9917,0.78453 -2.59375,1.04102 -0.60206,0.2565 -1.25593,0.46679 -1.45117,0.46679 -0.19524,0 -0.8266,0.19967 -1.4043,0.44336 -1.49053,0.62872 -4.39957,1.55664 -4.8789,1.55664 -0.22273,0 -0.87737,0.21112 -1.45508,0.47071 -0.5777,0.2596 -1.50078,0.5428 -2.05078,0.6289 -0.55,0.0861 -1.45,0.31245 -2,0.50196 -1.5175,0.52289 -3.80733,1.07949 -5.70704,1.38672 -0.93906,0.15187 -2.01648,0.44024 -2.39453,0.64257 -0.37805,0.20233 -1.27766,0.36914 -2,0.36914 -0.72233,0 -1.95103,0.225 -2.73047,0.5 -0.77943,0.275 -2.1112,0.50191 -2.95898,0.50391 -0.84779,0.002 -2.36667,0.22544 -3.375,0.49609 -1.00833,0.27064 -2.73398,0.4931 -3.83398,0.4961 -1.1,0.003 -3.35,0.22693 -5,0.49804 -3.96519,0.6515 -24.41406,0.64033 -28.16602,-0.0156 -1.375,-0.24041 -3.50582,-0.44748 -4.73438,-0.45898 -1.22855,-0.0115 -3.09655,-0.24454 -4.15234,-0.51954 -1.0558,-0.275 -2.52693,-0.5019 -3.26758,-0.5039 -0.74064,-0.002 -2.08245,-0.22699 -2.98242,-0.5 -0.89997,-0.27302 -2.1469,-0.4961 -2.77148,-0.4961 -0.62459,0 -1.40549,-0.14519 -1.73633,-0.32226 -0.33085,-0.17706 -1.41022,-0.46827 -2.39649,-0.64649 -0.98627,-0.17821 -2.46796,-0.49761 -3.29296,-0.71093 -2.99156,-0.77356 -5.18652,-1.38532 -6.16602,-1.7168 -0.55,-0.18613 -1.37565,-0.41215 -1.83398,-0.50195 -0.45834,-0.0898 -1.30512,-0.37454 -1.88282,-0.63282 -0.57771,-0.25828 -1.27275,-0.46875 -1.54492,-0.46875 -0.27217,0 -0.92409,-0.22417 -1.44922,-0.49804 -0.52512,-0.27387 -1.25638,-0.50472 -1.62304,-0.51172 -0.36667,-0.007 -0.95663,-0.23279 -1.3125,-0.50195 -0.35588,-0.26917 -0.90589,-0.48829 -1.22266,-0.48829 -0.31677,0 -1.00249,-0.2142 -1.52148,-0.4746 -0.51906,-0.26043 -1.61836,-0.72835 -2.44336,-1.04102 -0.825,-0.31267 -1.950004,-0.76752 -2.500004,-1.00977 -0.55,-0.24224 -1.9,-0.83618 -3,-1.32031 C 93.696919,277.40163 85.585077,273.3433 84,272.40234 c -0.641667,-0.38093 -1.766667,-1.01773 -2.5,-1.41601 -0.733333,-0.39828 -1.979221,-1.15904 -2.767578,-1.68945 -0.788357,-0.53047 -1.513471,-0.9629 -1.613281,-0.9629 -0.708543,0 -12.287023,-8.4427 -17.285157,-12.60351 -3.874206,-3.22517 -14.35083,-13.70278 -17.5625,-17.56445 -3.36491,-4.04591 -8.377982,-10.81896 -10.605468,-14.33008 -0.963183,-1.51824 -3.468848,-5.67647 -3.917969,-6.50196 C 27.498683,216.87565 26.912198,215.825 26.445312,215 c -1.895768,-3.34988 -5.779296,-11.35847 -5.779296,-11.91797 0,-0.2128 -1.148804,-2.81687 -1.689454,-3.82812 -0.170199,-0.31835 -0.310546,-0.8202 -0.310546,-1.11524 0,-0.29503 -0.203543,-0.9333 -0.453125,-1.41992 -0.498518,-0.97198 -1.121062,-2.66915 -1.546875,-4.21875 -0.278766,-1.01448 -0.615014,-2.06037 -1.337891,-4.16602 -0.220287,-0.64167 -0.507412,-1.76667 -0.638672,-2.5 -0.13126,-0.73333 -0.40177,-1.85833 -0.601562,-2.5 C 13.465698,181.3357 12.917667,178.90827 12.65625,177 c -0.138133,-1.00834 -0.418244,-2.25538 -0.621094,-2.77148 -0.20285,-0.5161 -0.36914,-1.61089 -0.36914,-2.4336 0,-0.82271 -0.213022,-2.50065 -0.47461,-3.72851 -1.2872624,-6.04223 -1.2772332,-28.59183 0.01563,-33.72071 0.252328,-1.00102 0.458985,-2.52831 0.458985,-3.39453 0,-0.86621 0.1616,-1.99667 0.357422,-2.51172 0.195821,-0.51505 0.485846,-1.83645 0.644531,-2.9375 0.414276,-2.87451 1.449819,-7.20717 2.392578,-10.00195 0.18553,-0.55 0.45833,-1.52435 0.605469,-2.16602 0.485619,-2.11777 2.897244,-8.98178 3.59375,-10.22851 0.223717,-0.40044 0.40625,-0.95047 0.40625,-1.22266 0,-0.2722 0.215184,-0.92043 0.478515,-1.43945 0.263331,-0.519029 0.923167,-1.917709 1.464844,-3.109376 C 22.98098,94.316518 25.919858,88.39968 26.742193,87 c 0.376989,-0.641666 1.010843,-1.766666 1.408203,-2.5 2.803385,-5.173689 9.850311,-15.066343 15.078125,-21.166016 4.61526,-5.384963 11.981756,-12.712902 16.253906,-16.167968 0.90676,-0.733334 2.180457,-1.793995 2.832031,-2.357422 4.15347,-3.591576 17.196925,-12.435125 21.019531,-14.251953 0.275,-0.130704 1.4,-0.74346 2.5,-1.361329 3.078637,-1.729258 8.509988,-4.372668 12.419922,-6.044921 0.59851,-0.255978 1.574786,-0.676703 2.167979,-0.933594 0.59314,-0.256891 1.75312,-0.724432 2.57812,-1.041016 0.825,-0.316585 1.95122,-0.766026 2.50194,-0.998047 0.55073,-0.232022 1.48513,-0.527959 2.07813,-0.658203 0.59299,-0.130244 1.16492,-0.375694 1.26954,-0.544922 0.10459,-0.169228 0.49516,-0.308593 0.86914,-0.308593 0.37397,0 1.15277,-0.200703 1.73047,-0.447266 0.57769,-0.246564 1.95077,-0.706409 3.05078,-1.021484 1.09999,-0.315075 2.45,-0.728296 3,-0.917969 0.55,-0.189674 1.52435,-0.455311 2.16602,-0.589844 0.64166,-0.134533 1.69231,-0.40884 2.33398,-0.611328 1.66374,-0.525029 4.20207,-1.080591 6.35741,-1.390625 1.02173,-0.146968 2.17546,-0.437388 2.5625,-0.644531 0.38705,-0.207142 1.36396,-0.376953 2.17188,-0.376953 0.80791,0 2.2055,-0.223078 3.10547,-0.496094 0.89997,-0.273015 2.43215,-0.498 3.40429,-0.5 0.97215,-0.002 2.77215,-0.216709 4,-0.478516 2.14098,-0.456505 12.27308,-1.008818 18.56446,-1.011718 z m 1.60546,100.664062 c 0.0213,0.0103 0.14192,0.0348 0.38282,0.0762 2.42137,0.41658 3.96421,0.63405 5.13086,0.79102 -0.002,-0.003 -0.004,-0.005 -0.006,-0.008 -1.95504,-0.42117 -5.64255,-0.92417 -5.50782,-0.85937 z m 5.08985,0.19531 c -0.007,0.007 0.17421,0.10569 0.30273,0.17969 0.10278,0.022 -0.14931,-0.0725 0.63867,0.23828 -0.65867,-0.31155 -0.9294,-0.42987 -0.9414,-0.41797 z m 64.33398,3.99024 c -0.18348,0.16819 -0.36494,0.33849 -0.55078,0.5039 0.42448,0.39568 0.72097,0.87731 0.92188,1.41211 -0.0716,-0.46482 -0.14093,-0.92986 -0.23633,-1.39062 -0.0272,-0.13122 -0.0982,-0.36992 -0.13477,-0.52539 z m 0.77149,4.65625 c 0.002,0.73041 -0.0361,1.40427 -0.0645,2.04687 0.005,-0.003 0.009,-0.006 0.0137,-0.01 l 0.35546,-0.25782 c -0.11917,-0.59021 -0.21856,-1.1837 -0.30468,-1.77929 z M 94.859375,139.67188 c -1.24712,0.30099 -1.973979,0.55471 -1.033203,0.57421 0.474213,0.01 0.947256,-0.002 1.419922,-0.0215 -0.128945,-0.18424 -0.258516,-0.36804 -0.386719,-0.55273 z m 6.414065,18.73046 c -0.002,0.01 0.0134,0.0409 0.0527,0.0977 0.12803,0.18482 0.25242,0.34579 0.37891,0.52148 0.023,-0.0475 0.0454,-0.0951 0.0684,-0.14257 -0.26063,-0.28199 -0.492,-0.51107 -0.5,-0.47657 z m -20.728518,7.05274 c -0.01005,0.20101 -0.0066,0.28419 -0.02734,0.57226 -0.0039,0.0548 -0.01494,0.10745 -0.01953,0.16211 0.194888,0.009 0.388947,0.024 0.583984,0.0312 -0.182015,-0.24308 -0.359975,-0.50265 -0.537109,-0.76562 z m 11.859375,24.2207 c -0.313869,0.0394 -0.627384,0.0773 -0.939453,0.11914 -0.06039,0.0482 -0.125827,0.0896 -0.185547,0.13867 -0.987013,0.8108 -0.25008,0.50624 1.125,-0.25781 z m -8.574219,3.67578 c -0.0011,0.005 -0.0028,0.0108 -0.0039,0.0156 -0.04358,0.1984 -0.132505,0.40836 -0.236328,0.61133 1.269427,0.82339 3.490521,1.56631 2.675781,0.98046 -0.790143,-0.56815 -1.607929,-1.09494 -2.435547,-1.60742 z m 85.498042,128.95313 -2.35546,0.0976 -2.35547,0.0977 -0.67578,1.66602 c -0.37111,0.91667 -0.88382,2.23046 -1.14063,2.91796 -1.8295,4.89764 -2.44162,6.47747 -3.01367,7.79883 -0.2501,0.57774 -0.45313,1.26115 -0.45313,1.51758 0,0.25647 -0.12087,0.60903 -0.26757,0.7832 -0.14669,0.17416 -0.60908,1.21641 -1.02735,2.31641 -0.41826,1.1 -0.99078,2.60064 -1.27148,3.33398 -0.28071,0.73333 -0.69993,1.85833 -0.9336,2.5 -0.75043,2.06076 -1.57015,4.1447 -1.9414,4.9375 -0.28277,0.60387 -0.25614,0.83827 0.12304,1.07813 0.64998,0.41097 2.87493,0.39958 3.65821,-0.0195 0.34659,-0.18546 0.77874,-0.82427 0.95898,-1.41797 0.73381,-2.417 1.28531,-3.61613 2.03125,-4.41016 0.77746,-0.8279 0.84151,-0.83593 6.34961,-0.83593 5.12382,0 5.63255,0.0551 6.44141,0.6914 0.48305,0.37996 0.87986,0.86812 0.88086,1.08399 0.001,0.21587 0.2017,0.77748 0.44726,1.24804 0.24556,0.47054 0.55714,1.29423 0.69141,1.83203 0.48399,1.9399 1.97821,2.59621 4.41992,1.94141 0.68105,-0.18264 0.70111,-0.26479 0.28516,-1.24609 -0.42764,-1.0089 -1.01878,-2.53186 -2.08789,-5.38282 -0.275,-0.73334 -0.70002,-1.85834 -0.94336,-2.5 -0.24334,-0.64167 -0.97898,-2.59231 -1.63477,-4.33398 -0.65578,-1.74166 -1.33933,-3.42776 -1.51953,-3.74609 -0.1802,-0.31837 -0.32812,-0.74528 -0.32812,-0.94922 0,-0.20394 -0.20303,-0.84417 -0.45313,-1.42188 -0.49669,-1.14731 -1.34195,-3.29704 -2.11523,-5.38281 -0.27188,-0.73333 -0.7822,-1.97651 -1.13282,-2.76367 z m -31.99414,0.0293 v 14.44336 c 0,7.94447 0.10221,14.54753 0.22852,14.67383 0.12631,0.1262 2.86446,0.18857 6.08398,0.13867 L 149.5,351.5 l 0.0996,-2.07227 0.0977,-2.07226 -3.75586,-0.0937 c -3.62976,-0.0912 -3.77103,-0.12251 -4.17774,-0.92774 -0.31462,-0.6229 -0.42178,-3.75956 -0.42578,-12.41796 l -0.004,-11.58204 h -2 z m 53.01758,0.0449 c -0.26595,-0.007 -0.5787,0.002 -0.95117,0.0215 L 187.5,322.5 l -0.0879,14.16602 c -0.0478,7.79167 -0.0137,14.35482 0.0742,14.58398 0.0948,0.24697 0.76352,0.41602 1.64258,0.41602 2.72226,0 2.53711,0.70387 2.53711,-9.66016 0,-10.50593 0.0999,-10.95303 1.9707,-8.82227 0.57853,0.65891 1.44368,1.82405 1.92187,2.58985 1.15756,1.85373 2.39601,3.77052 6.25196,9.66992 1.77674,2.71836 3.30955,5.14839 3.40625,5.40039 0.20874,0.54397 2.75447,0.98542 3.94922,0.68555 l 0.84179,-0.21094 -0.0879,-14.4082 -0.0859,-14.41016 h -2 -2 l -0.16796,9.26172 c -0.13693,7.60951 -0.2527,9.31704 -0.6504,9.5625 -0.26625,0.16437 -0.61573,0.21709 -0.77734,0.11719 -0.26319,-0.16267 -5.23541,-7.55515 -5.52148,-8.20899 -0.27122,-0.61988 -6.35898,-9.78441 -6.86328,-10.33203 -0.32459,-0.3525 -0.70409,-0.50198 -1.50196,-0.52148 z M 113.5,322.5 l -0.0879,14.16602 c -0.0478,7.79167 -0.0137,14.35482 0.0742,14.58398 0.17734,0.46214 3.08082,0.57532 3.75586,0.14648 0.29313,-0.18623 0.4347,-2.00171 0.5,-6.4121 l 0.0918,-6.1504 1.83204,-0.26953 c 5.86273,-0.86103 7.73945,-1.75749 9.24414,-4.41406 1.02851,-1.8158 1.05053,-5.2627 0.0469,-7.24609 -0.80585,-1.59235 -2.44282,-3.20046 -3.44726,-3.38672 -0.37201,-0.069 -1.50144,-0.30028 -2.50977,-0.51367 -1.00833,-0.21339 -3.55768,-0.41352 -5.66602,-0.44532 z m 6.52539,4.23047 c 0.44297,0.0128 1.01487,0.14045 1.9707,0.39062 2.77024,0.72506 3.44922,1.38449 3.44922,3.35547 0,1.85401 -0.62897,2.62855 -2.70508,3.33594 -1.99556,0.67994 -3.49522,0.65924 -4.38476,-0.0625 -0.65066,-0.52787 -0.71039,-0.85324 -0.62109,-3.41406 0.0968,-2.775 0.11845,-2.83928 1.0957,-3.30664 0.43895,-0.20991 0.75234,-0.31162 1.19531,-0.29883 z m 47.35547,2.93555 c 0.45662,0 0.88489,0.87977 2.51367,5.16796 0.27854,0.73333 0.71617,1.82571 0.97266,2.42774 0.25649,0.60207 0.46679,1.53826 0.46679,2.08203 v 0.99023 h -4.11132 c -2.26111,0 -4.21177,-0.10041 -4.33399,-0.22265 -0.3077,-0.3077 -0.27842,-1.57697 0.0449,-1.96094 0.14669,-0.17416 0.60736,-1.21641 1.02344,-2.31641 0.41608,-1.1 0.97019,-2.49365 1.23242,-3.0957 0.26222,-0.60205 0.47657,-1.29088 0.47657,-1.53125 0,-0.56964 1.08064,-1.54101 1.71484,-1.54101 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="display:inline;fill:#0748cb;stroke-width:0.33333334"       
       d="m 80.550153,210.43904 c -0.12519,-0.12519 -0.12591,-2.25431 -0.0017,-4.73137 0.19849,-3.95513 0.32096,-4.64365 1.0054,-5.65223 0.48809,-0.71924 0.779376,-1.63536 0.779376,-2.45121 0,-0.96798 0.218264,-1.50501 0.849384,-2.08991 0.468133,-0.43385 0.935903,-1.32035 1.04214,-1.975 0.12186,-0.75095 0.419716,-1.25985 0.809846,-1.38367 0.358797,-0.11388 0.760204,-0.72733 0.958994,-1.46557 0.3644,-1.35329 1.35309,-2.80573 2.585056,-3.79761 0.41509,-0.33414 0.75465,-0.86578 0.75465,-1.18141 0,-0.31564 0.5625,-1.18797 1.25,-1.93852 3.105484,-3.39027 4.083334,-4.53253 4.083334,-4.76989 0,-0.14031 0.455973,-0.44398 z"
       id="path4566"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Had to remove some of the svg plotting above to fit in the space allocated.

This was the only way I could get a local SVG file to display in the latest version of Firefox:

```
<svg id="svgtest2"><use xlink:href="./ValueChain1Plan.svg" fill="red"></use></svg>
```

It however ignores my fill of red, not sure if this is due to the style within the SVG itself, although if I remove that it says the SVG file is invalid.

The following CSS all gets ignored:

```
svg#svg4554 g #path4570 {
    fill:#ff0000;
}

svg g > path:nth-of-type(1){
    fill:#ff0000;
}
```

How can I change the colour of one SVG referenced multiple times for a specific path in that SVG?

Comment: If the styling is actually in the SVG I'm pretty sure you can't. It's always going to win in the cascade,

Comment: Can't remove it from there and there seems to be no way to tell Inkscape to do so either.

Comment: Surely this is all standard stuff that everyone needs to do. Can't believe this sucks so much.

Comment: Inkscape leave a lot of unnecessary crud in it's SVG output. If you run it through an optimiser you might have better luck. - https://css-tricks.com/tools-for-optimizing-svg/

Comment: svgo optimization didn't help and it still has the fill in the svg file