# style specific path of SVG all browsers

Tags: css, svg

IS it possible to style a specific path of an SVG in all browsers? I have tried this:

HTML

```
<svg display="none" width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs>
    <symbol id="icon-facebook" viewBox="0 0 1024 1024">
      <title>facebook</title>
      <path class="path1" d="M512 1024c-281.6 0-512-230.4-512-512s230.4-512 512-512c281.6 0 512 230.4 512 512s-230.4 512-512 512zM512 66.56c-245.76 0-445.44 199.68-445.44 445.44s199.68 445.44 445.44 445.44 445.44-199.68 445.44-445.44-199.68-445.44-445.44-445.44z"></path>
      <path class="path2" d="M391.68 770.56c0 2.56 5.12 5.12 7.68 2.56s43.52-51.2 56.32-99.84c2.56-12.8 23.040-81.92 23.040-81.92 10.24 20.48 43.52 38.4 76.8 38.4 99.84 0 166.4-89.6 166.4-207.36 0-89.6-76.8-174.080-197.12-174.080-148.48 0-222.72 102.4-222.72 189.44 0 51.2 20.48 97.28 64 115.2 7.68 2.56 12.8 0 15.36-7.68 2.56-5.12 5.12-17.92 5.12-23.040 2.56-7.68 2.56-10.24-5.12-17.92-12.8-15.36-20.48-33.28-20.48-58.88 0-76.8 58.88-145.92 153.6-145.92 84.48 0 128 48.64 128 115.2 0 87.040-38.4 161.28-97.28 161.28-33.28 0-56.32-25.6-48.64-58.88 10.24-38.4 28.16-79.36 28.16-107.52 0-25.6-12.8-46.080-40.96-46.080-33.28 0-58.88 33.28-58.88 79.36 0 28.16 10.24 48.64 10.24 48.64s-33.28 140.8-40.96 163.84c-12.8 51.2-2.56 110.080-2.56 115.2z"></path>
      <path class="path3" d="M990.72 512c0 264.39-214.33 478.72-478.72 478.72s-478.72-214.33-478.72-478.72c0-264.39 214.33-478.72 478.72-478.72s478.72 214.33 478.72 478.72z"></path>
      <path class="path4" d="M512 1024c-281.6 0-512-230.4-512-512s230.4-512 512-512 512 230.4 512 512-230.4 512-512 512zM512 66.56c-245.76 0-445.44 199.68-445.44 445.44s199.68 445.44 445.44 445.44 445.44-199.68 445.44-445.44c0-245.76-199.68-445.44-445.44-445.44z"></path>
      <path class="path5" d="M442.88 770.56h102.4c0 0 0-143.36 0-258.56h76.8l10.24-102.4h-81.92v-40.96c0-20.48 12.8-25.6 23.040-25.6s58.88 0 58.88 0v-87.040h-79.36c-87.040 0-107.52 66.56-107.52 107.52v46.080h-51.2v102.4h51.2c-2.56 117.76-2.56 258.56-2.56 258.56z"></path>
    </symbol>
</defs>
</svg>
<svg class="icon icon-facebook"><use xlink:href="#icon-facebook"></use></svg>
```

CSS

```
#icon-facebook .path1, #icon-facebook .path2, #icon-facebook .path3, #icon-facebook .path4 {
        fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
#icon-facebook .path5, #icon-facebook .path1, #icon-facebook .path4  {
   fill: rgb(109, 103, 101);

}
```

IT works in Firefox but not in safari, chrome internet explorer, is it not possible?

Comment: Firefox is broken, the other UAs do it right. I.e. it should not be possible.

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13674240) (no css styling of svg elements referenced through `use`), I think it won't work. The answer has aged a bit, though, maybe there is a way to make it work (possibly through RaphaelJS ?)

Comment: What you have posted works fine in Chrome. IE, etc. http://jsfiddle.net/2wu475wn/  Have you perhaps missed a second part from your question?  For instance, are you trying to do something like `.icon-facebook .path5  { fill: blue; }`? Because that won't work.  You can't style elements across a `<use>` boundary.

Comment: can you change the opacity too?

Comment: Yes. Just use `opacity` or `fill-opacity` depending on how you want the opacity to work.  http://jsfiddle.net/2wu475wn/2/