# SVG path animation not working in chrome

Tags: css, svg

```
.circle{
  opacity:1;
  stroke-dasharray: 150;
  stroke-dashoffset: 150;
  -webkit-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s 0.5s ease-out;
}

.drawn svg .circle{
  opacity: 1;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

**Fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/cq26yjp2/

Works fine in Firefox, not sure what seems to be the problem

Comment: You'r relying on a Firefox bug: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673441/svg-use-element-and-hover-style/13674240#13674240 Unfortunatly, the fix there only applies to colors, not arbitrary attributes.