# Changing CSS with SVG <symbols> on hover

Tags: css, svg

I'm working on a handful of SVG icons as `<symbol>` that I want to be able to alter on `:hover`, `:focus`, and `:active`.  Specifically, I need to be able to change the color of specific paths within an SVG.  Normally, with any other element, I can do something like this

```
.parent .child {
    fill: blue;
}
.parent:hover .child {
    fill: red;
}
```

However, when applying this to my SVG symbols, it just doesn't work.  Not many discussions from what I can find in the last couple of years on problems changing css with shadow-DOM stuff like SVG symbols, but the just using CurrentColor won't work for me because I need to do it with two colors.

I have a CodePen up with my scenario [here](https://codepen.io/cameronlewis35/pen/mBrbJr)

It seems like this should be straightforward but I've been tied up in knots over it for awhile.  Anybody have any thoughts that might help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and post it here.

Comment: See codepen link i posted originally https://codepen.io/cameronlewis35/pen/mBrbJr

Comment: This [blog post](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) on styling `<use>` might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar question was asked here: [SVG USE element and :hover style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673441/svg-use-element-and-hover-style)

The problem is that elements that are referenced by `use` aren't really part of the DOM, so you can't access them with CSS. However, some properties that are set on the `use` element itself (like `fill` or `color`) will trickle down to the referenced elements.

So, first of all, our CSS can only change the `use` element. Then we need to use some of the tricks in the [article](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/07/16/styling-svg-use-content-css/) @Matheus mentioned to handle the different colors. This means changing the SVG code for the `symbol`s a little. If the icons only need two colors per state, we can use `fill` + `color/currentColor`:

```
<g id="icon_alarm">
    <g class="transflip">
        <path class="transflip" d="M8 1.3c-3.6 ....." />
        <path class="transflip" d="M1 5.1C1.7 3....." />
    </g>
    <g class="fillflip">
        <path class="fillflip" fill="currentColor" d="M11.7 8......" />
    </g>
    ...
```

---

```
.icon use {
    fill: transparent;
    color: #007fa3;
}
.icon:hover  use {
    fill: #007fa3;
    color: transparent;
}
```

If the icons need more colors per state, we can use [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables) and add `style="fill: var(--my-special-color)"` styles in the SVG (also a trick from the mentioned article), but that doesn't work in some browsers, e.g. IE/Edge.

Updated pen using both techniques: https://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/GMjgxJ?editors=1100

Comment: You, my friend, are a wizard.  I don't think I properly understood the color/currentColor solution before, which is why I didn't think it would work here.  Your solution is excellent.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
html:hover .transflip {
  fill: red;
}
```

This kind of hover works. I noticed you used same class for `g` and `path`. I'd try not to.

I'd also **try to wrap each svg inside a `div` with width and height**, and then use `:focus` etc. on that `div` since svg elements seem not to recognize pseudoselectors on your pen.