# Change svg rect stroke that was placed by use

Tags: javascript, css, svg, colors, shadow-dom

I am working with svg sprites and I'm trying to change the stroke property in some svg that was placed by **use** feature. It places the extended svg by ShadowRoot into the DOM and looks like it locked from the outer css rules.

But I have seen the possible solution with **use** in styles but it doesn't work. Does anyone can help me, please? Is it possible to do it at all?

```
<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="test">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100" stroke="green"/> 
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg id="some" class="icon"><use xlink:href="#test" /></svg>

#some use rect {
 stroke: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two IDs the same and you need to remove the stroke from the symboland apply to the `use` class.

```css
#test {
  fill: none;
}

.red {
  stroke: red;
}

.green {
  stroke: green;
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none;">
  <symbol id="test">
      <rect x="10" y="10" width="100" height="100"/> 
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#test" class="red"/></svg>

<svg class="icon"><use xlink:href="#test" class="green"/></svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  Hmm, but what about case when I have some rect and path in my **use** svg and I want to do only for rect stroke - red?

P.s. I have tried to implement your suggestion but it doesn't work unfortunately

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that.

Comment: See this answer for a way to push different colors through to a `<symbol>`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46354931/1869660