# Click events not triggered in FF on SVG elements included via the "use" tag

Tags: javascript, html, events, svg, click

Click events on SVG elements are not triggered in Firefox if the element is included via the `use` tag from `defs`.

Best explained with an live example:

```js
const paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
const toggleColor = (event) => {
 let path = event.currentTarget;
 path.setAttribute('fill', ('lightblue' === path.getAttribute('fill')) ? '#FFDC00' : 'lightblue');
}

paths.forEach(path => { path.addEventListener('click', toggleColor); });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px lightgrey;
}

svg {
  margin: 16px 40px;
}

path {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Path directly embedded in SVG -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Clicking the star toggles the color in all browsers.</div>

  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" version="1.1">
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="lightgrey"></circle>
    <path stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" fill="lightblue" d=" M 60.000  80.000 L 80.000  94.641 L 77.321  70.000 L 100.000 60.000 L 77.321  50.000 L 80.000  25.359 L 60.000  40.000 L 40.000  25.359 L 42.679  50.000 L 20.000  60.000 L 42.679  70.000 L 40.000  94.641 z"/>
  </svg>

</div>

<!-- Path embedded in SVG with the use tag -->
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Clicking the star toggles the color in Chrome but not in FF.</div>

  <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="120" height="120" version="1.1">
    <defs>
      <path id="star" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" fill="lightblue" d=" M 60.000  80.000 L 80.000  94.641 L 77.321  70.000 L 100.000 60.000 L 77.321  50.000 L 80.000  25.359 L 60.000  40.000 L 40.000  25.359 L 42.679  50.000 L 20.000  60.000 L 42.679  70.000 L 40.000  94.641 z"/>
    </defs>
    
    <circle cx="60" cy="60" r="60" fill="lightgrey"></circle>
    <use xlink:href="#star"></use>
  </svg>

</div>
```

I guess this is related to [SVG USE element and :hover style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13673441/svg-use-element-and-hover-style).

Is this behavior spec compliant and is there any way to install click events on such items reliably?

Handling click events on the whole SVG and manually checking the coordinates is not really an option since that would be really hard to implement 100% accurate (recognize only clicks on star itself, not on transparent parts from its bounding rect etc.).